# Syntax Error while filtering Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `badges` from which I want to create a subset `badges_gold`. The condition of subset is that the `UserId` present in `badges` should be present in the list `gold_users`. But when I use `is in` operation I get `invalid syntax` error. How to fix this?

**Main Dataframe - badges**

```
UserId | Name
  1    | Altruist
  2    | Autobiographer
  3    | Enlightened
  4    | Citizen Patrol
  5    | python
```

**List of Gold Badge Users - gold_users**

```
gold_users = [1,2,3]
```

**Code**

```
badges_gold = badges[badges.UserId is in gold_users]
```

**Expected Output - badges_gold**

```
UserId | Name
  1    | Altruist
  2    | Autobiographer
  3    | Enlightened
```

**Error**

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: write `in` rather than `is in`

Comment: I had tried it but using `in` gave the following error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` @Danis

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make the below change and it will do the job for you.

```
badges[badges.UserId.isin(gold_users)]
```